# How to catch specific error “Lost connection to MySQL server during query”

Tags: python, mysql

I am using

```
def mysql_handling(string):
    global cursor
    while True:
        try: 
            cursor.execute(string)
            if 'SELECT' not in string:
                db.commit()
            break
        except MySQLdb.MySQLError:
            cursor.close()
                    print 'something went wrong!!'
            time.sleep(1)
            cursor = get_cursor()
```

To retry the query if the connection fails, but I **ONLY** want to retry the connection when I have the error **“Lost connection to MySQL server during query”**. (else the mysql_handling function gets in an infinite loop)

So what should I use instead of *'except MySQLdb.MySQLError:'* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-apiref-errors-error.html) it would seem that you can't really catch an exception that is that specific but need to go as close as you can ([OperationalError](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-apiref-errors-operationalerror.html)) and check errno for the [exact error code](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-messages-client.html);

```
except MySQLdb.OperationalError as err:

    if err.errno == errorcode.CR_SERVER_LOST:
        # This is the error you're looking for
    else:
        # This is not the error you're looking for
        raise
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of while True, you can try connecting and commiting again in except block.

```
def mysql_handling(string):
    global cursor
    try: 
        cursor.execute(string)
        if 'SELECT' not in string:
            db.commit()
    except MySQLdb.MySQLError:
        cursor.close()
                print 'something went wrong!!'
        time.sleep(1)
        cursor = get_cursor()
        cursor.execute(string)
        if 'SELECT' not in string:
            db.commit()
    finally:
            if cursor:
                cursor.close()
```

or u can keep max number of retries say like 5.